# Where can I go to avoid planes overhead?

Tags: air-travel, remote-locations

Where on Earth can I go and not see or hear planes flying overhead?

To clarify: I would like to be able to pretend that planes do not exist for a period of at least one month. Faint noise and contrails are all unacceptable (chemtrails too!).

Further clarification: I would still like to see the sky. Hiding in a cave or building is not acceptable. You may assume I am a human with excellent hearing and vision. I would prefer to be on dry land. An expedition to a remote location is allowed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93127/discussion-on-question-by-fab-von-bellingshausen-where-can-i-go-to-avoid-planes).

Comment: I seem to recall an identical question on [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: Remotely related, but for roads rather than airplanes: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1857/566

Comment: Please post your chat comments in the chatroom. (I will delete them if posted here.) Only useful links will stay for now.

Answer (score 52):

This web site shows the location of all (registered) flights that are currently in the air https://www.flightradar24.com/

You can check for a specific location or just look at the overall pattern. Obviously there are a lot more flights in the northern half of the globe and flight density is a lot sparser the further south you go.

At the time of this writing, there are no planes across the Amazonian area and large parts of Southern South America (with the exception of the Pacific coast). There is only one flight in the entire South Atlantic south of St. Helena. Tibet is mostly flight free. My current location is free for about 10 miles but BA175 from LHR to JFK will pass over in about a minute or two.

Comment: It only shows (or at leased only used to show) flights that have an ADS-B transponder. It also used not to show flights that are out of range of one of their receivers, but it looks like they're now attempting to predict flight paths for planes that have gone out of range.

Comment: Soon, we'll have ADS-B receiver coverage everywhere!  https://aireon.com/resources/overview-materials/its-just-ads-b/

Comment: Related: [What (if any) regularly scheduled airline flights pass over Antarctica?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4310/31076)

Comment: It doesn't appear to cover independent pilots on recreational runs.

Comment: @crokusek it shows some of them, not all, as ADS-B isn't yet a requirement for all of them (but will be soon, there's currently a grace period given to owners to install the equipment in their aircraft).

Comment: @crokusek Those probably rarely reach remote places.

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/stories-47585703 And just because they are supposed to go a way doesn't mean they will, either because they don't go that way in the first place or they have to divert

Answer (score 48):

### [Donbass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donbass)

This is a region in eastern Ukraine under control of pro-Russian rebels.  Airlines used to freely overfly war zones with low level conflicts like this, because the belief was rebels only had small shoulder-fired SAMs like Stinger and SA-7, which were short-range.  Actually, the rebels had Buk and other advanced, truck-mounted high altitude SAMs.  They were vigorously targeting Ukranian Air Force planes (who had started flying high to avoid SA-7s), until they accidentally shot down a Boeing 777 jetliner, [Malaysian MH17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_17).   Now airlines avoid it like the plague.

The risk may not be high *now* four years gone, but the basic political situation on the ground has not changed.  The same rebels control the area, and they still have high altitude SAMs. So if an airline routed a flight over it, *and somehow their airplane did get shot down*, they could not possibly justify it: their civil liability would be out of this world. The dispatchers might even go to jail!

The Ukranian military doesn't like to fly there, same reason.   The Russians don't like to fly there because they *don't* claim it's part of Russia, and they don't want to stir the political pot by letting Ukraine and NATO catch them violating the Ukraine border.

Also, [here's an interesting (but by no means conclusive) map](https://www.newshub.co.nz/home/travel/2018/07/record-number-of-planes-in-the-air-at-once.html).

Comment: nice lateral thinking there. Though maybe the contrails left by missiles flying overhead would disqualify the region.

Comment: @jwenting Especially for someone concerned about chemtrails, a region well known for coal mining and smelting doesn't sound like a great destination. Then there are the rebels, but IMO those are no more dangerous than an active volcano, and that was already suggested as well.

Comment: @jwenting No need to fire anti-aircraft missiles when there are no aircraft.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev fun fact, the question doesn't actually specify the asker doesn't like war zones. Just that they don't like aircrafts. Though I suppose missile contrails would still be an issue, if the fighting is entirely on the ground, as far as the OP is concerned, that's fine.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I take the chemtrail line to be humor.

Comment: @DavidRicherby There's more missiles than SAMs. Think cruise missiles, anti-tank missiles, and long range missiles launched by aircraft outside the no-fly zone to targets inside it.

Answer (score 28):

The middle of the Tibetan plateau might be an option. Long-haul airliners don't fly there because in case of a pressurization failure it would take too long to reach air with safely breathable pressure.

It ought to be possible to find a place that avoids the few domestic routes to/from Tibet's own airports that are pointed to in comments -- especially in the western part of the plateau.

Comment: Do you have a source for that, or at least an explanation of why being over the Tibetan plateau affects the time required to reach air with safely breathable pressure?

Comment: @phoog I suspect that the answer is that even if the plane landed on the plateau, it would still be above the "safe breathing pressure" level.

Comment: @phoog: In case cabin pressurization fails, an airliner needs to descend to below 10,000 feet above sea level within at most 20 minutes before the oxygen generators for the passenger's masks run dry. In Tibet, the ground is so high that there _is_ no air to fly in below 10,000 feet. And in contrast to most other high elevations, there's no lowland nearby to fly to in a hurry.

Comment: Not true. First, you can [fly into Tibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lhasa_Gonggar_Airport), that's how most people get there especially before they built the train. Aircraft that fly over Tibet are equipped with [extended duration oxygen systems](https://boeing.mediaroom.com/2011-08-01-Boeing-Delivers-Milestone-737-with-High-Altitude-High-Temperature-Operation-Features). British Airways and Qantas traditionally did this because Tibet is in between HKG and Europe.

Comment: @IanF1 then I suppose the safe breathing pressure level is so low because of the motion of the plane through the air?  Certainly, there are airports above 10,000 ft. elevation, where airplanes can depressurize and people can disembark without supplemental oxygen.

Comment: @phoog People who can take a flight from an airport above 10,000 ft self select to reduce people with altitude sickness. But much more importantly is the rate of change. Most people adapt if they go to higher altitudes over a period of time, which they won't have here. Also physical exhaustion makes altitude sickness worse. I'd think the 10,000 ft are mostly a safety precaution to limit the danger for people already at a higher risk .

Comment: @Voo but people can take a flight *to* such an airport without any such self selection.

Comment: @phoog And people who do that can run into serious health problems.

Comment: Mount Everest has [similar troubles with planes](https://www.indiatoday.in/lifestyle/travel/story/do-planes-fly-over-mount-everest-frequent-flyer-reveals-chilling-answers-1488398-2019-03-28), and if the OP managed to spend the whole month up there, they'd be enormously fameous, as the current world record is only [32 hours](https://www.redbull.com/gb-en/everest-world-records).

Comment: @Voo Many people fly to Leh (I did). How do you propose to predict whether you will or will not have AMS? I do not know of any reliable screening. Most people do just fine. BTW if you choose the road instead you have to cross passes at more than 17000 feet which can be much worse.

Comment: @Vladimir We're talking about the reasons why even if there are airports above 10,000ft, the precaution of trying to get below that altitude in case of an emergency still makes sense. Surely you'll agree that "Most people do just fine" is not a sensible measure for an emergency procedure. It's all about risk management.

Comment: @Voo You're assuming there's a requirement against exposing passengers to pressure altitudes over 10,000 feet in an airplane depressurization, but there isn't. The [limit is actually 15,000 feet](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.841) long-term and 25,000 feet for 2 minutes. Regardless, as I said, aircraft flying over mountainous terrain carry extra oxygen and have [preplanned escape routes](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Mountainous_Terrain_Escape_Routes), there's no inherent limit.

Comment: @phoog I have a form of anemia and know that if I travel to far above sea level I will experience shortness of breathe and other symptoms. I could not now for example visit high mountains in the Alps as I one did, unless I took steps.

Comment: @user71659, I stand corrected regarding 15,000 feet rather than 10,000 -- though your Skybrary link quotes 14,000 feet and speaks about _"pre-planned escape route that must also allow further descent to below 10,000' within 30 minutes of emergency oxygen supply exhaustion"_. On the other hand, Wikipedia says that the average elevation in the northwestern part of the plateau exceeds 16,000 feet anyway, so these differences are not quite dispositive.

Comment: In any case, whether or not airlines _strictly need to_ avoid flying over Tibet, it can be observed that _in practice they do_. There are direct flights from Delhi to Beijing or Almaty where the shortest route would go over Tibet, but according to flight tracking websites both of these go the long way around instead (which in case of Almaty is the _very long_ way around, also avoiding Pakistan and Afghanistan). Similarly for Alamaty to Kuala Lumpur or San Fransisco to Delhi.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What happens is that with extended duration O2, they have 30 minutes of O2 + 30 minutes of intermediate altitude to land in Tibet. That's easily doable. Once the plane is stopped, the requirements don't apply. Not all airlines go over Tibet, sure, but as I said Qantas and BA are outfitted. Regardless, there's definitely regular flights into [numerous high-altitude Tibetan airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest_airports), (for which there are political reasons so to do) therefore it does not meet the OP's criteria.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's not just the mountains that are the issue with Tibet. [PRC allows extremely limited access to Tibetian airspace.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/30855/755) You probably won't see the PRC military aircraft operating there on FR24, though.

Comment: @user71659 The great circle from almost all of Europe to Hong Kong misses Tibet, mostly by quite some margin. I can believe that they used to fly over Tibet during the Soviet Era when overflight of the USSR was banned but, today, they probably go over Kazakhstan, Russia and Xinjiang. In fact, they sometimes even go over Mongolia and approach Hong Kong from due north, some way north of the great circle. Overflight of Tibet is very restricted, today.

Answer (score 17):

Antarctica should be a pretty safe place; the only flights you would need to worry about are the flights to and from the bases which will be few and far between (especially when compared to the daily flight activity over pretty much every other continent) and a very limited number of tourist flights. Part of the reason is that there are [no scheduled flights from either of the three southern hemisphere continents that pass over Antarctica proper](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4310). In case the evidence there is not enough there is also a [non-SE source](https://www.quora.com/Do-any-airline-flights-fly-over-Antarctica-If-not-why-not) which points out *why* they don’t do it and why they would be unlikely to detour even with (un)favourable winds.

You can improve your position in Antarctica by staying away from the flight routes from the bases to their restock positions (i.e. the direct route to Christchurch for most of them). I couldn’t find a map of where and how far south the tourist flights go (they don’t land, they attempt to show a scenery) but I suspect they wouldn’t go too far inland.

Comment: There are [tourist flights](https://www.antarcticaflights.com.au/) over Antarctica. One [famously crashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_New_Zealand_Flight_901).

Comment: @user71659 I forgot to mention those but the same consideration applies

Comment: @user71659, tourist flights mostly stick to the coast, where all the interesting stuff is.  If you stick to the interior away from the Australia->South Pole and New Zealand->South Pole routes, you can probably go years without seeing an airplane.

Answer (score 16):

You can go to the vicinity of a volcanic eruption.

https://www.businessinsider.com/why-planes-do-not-fly-during-volcanic-eruption-2017-11

I do not know how you will get there.  You can not fly there.

Comment: I would note that this will need to be a very major volcanic eruption. Most eruptions don't close enough airspace to prevent you from seeing planes or contrails in the sky. For example, millions upon millions of people flew to or from Hawaii while Kilauea was erupting violently last summer - including to and from 2 different commercial airports on the same island as the volcano. Lots of air traffic would have been quite visible from the volcano at the time. You need an eruption that throws a lot of ash well into the upper atmosphere to really shut down air traffic in the region.

Comment: Isn't this option disqualified by virtue of one not being able to see the sky?

Comment: Not really helpful.

Answer (score 15):

Last year I spent a week's holiday on the western-most point of the island of La Palma, one of the Canary Islands.  Had a great view of the Atlantic Ocean and didn't see any aircraft all week long.

Comment: How did you arrive there?

Comment: There is [La Palma Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Palma_Airport) and if the island was square it would 27 x 27 km: *"there are flights to the main Europe cities and charter flights from mainland Europe such as Germany, United Kingdom, Scandinavia and the Netherlands. In 2018, the airport had 1,420,277 passengers "*. The prevailing winds are from the north-east, so I presume planes would to have approach from southern and western directions. Perhaps the astronomical observatories mean the planes must always take southern routes (the western-most point is in the north-west corner)?

Comment: Arrived by plane :-)  The runway is oriented north-south, so aircraft all approach from either the north or south, and all routes connect with other European destinations.  The western-most point was about 2 hrs drive from the airport and on the other side of a 2600 m tall volcano.  The point is, there is no reason for commercial aircraft to be on the western side of the island to access the island's airport; nor do I recall seeing any other aircraft during my stay - no trans-atlantic airliners destined for elsewhere or even local general aviation.

Comment: Hmm, I'm finding it a harder to find a counterexample to this than most other proposed answers. It looks like most of the Europe to South America routes tend to pass over Tenerife or Gran Canaria instead, or alternatively several hundred kilometers west of La Palma. +1

Comment: @Nick, you should add that to your answer.

Answer (score 12):

I am surprised that no one mentioned Beijing. Downtown Beijing, within the 3rd Belt Highway, is a no-fly zone except for the occasional military aviation. Also, the smog makes it difficult to see anything in the sky :-) Good chances are that, in a month's time, you won't see any aviation at all.

It seems to me that the city of Paris is also a (sort of) no-fly zone, in that aircraft may not fly lower than 6,000 ft. Both Paris and Beijing's airports are way outside of the central city. However, Paris is very small, so I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: Why did nobody mention it?  Because the question is tagged [tag:remote-places].

Comment: Washington, D.C. is also a no-fly zone, and yet I can personally guarantee you that you will see and hear lots and lots of airplanes if you go there. A no-fly zone would need to be hundreds of miles wide in order to see no contrails from the center of it in most cases. Granted, Beijing might work a little better than most, due to the pollution obscuring the view of the contrails.

Comment: @reirab DC is very, very small. Beijing, even within the 3rd Belt Hwy, is quite large. Also, yes, the smog makes it very difficult to see anything high up, including planes :-)

Comment: @xuq01 The third ring road is only 8.5 miles wide. Even from the center of it, you should be able to see airplanes from 25 times that distance or more on a clear day. Incidentally, Washington, D.C. is about 11 miles wide.

Comment: @reirab Well, I don't think there are very "clear" days in Beijing :-)

Answer (score 7):

I found an interesting visualization called [Flight Stream](https://callumprentice.github.io/apps/flight_stream/index.html) that connects the worlds major airports with each other and simulates air traffic.  While the flight paths are not accurate, this does show the type of patterns you would expect in a 30 day period, and the outlook isn't good for your question.  After looking around for a while, I can't find a place other than maybe parts of Greenland or extreme North Russia.  The North Pole isn't technically land, but it seems pretty free of flights according to this.

Contrails from large jets can be seen from 200 miles away, so when you look at this map, keep in mind that each of the flight paths should be about 200 miles wide.  You're basically looking for a 400 mile wide area that has no flight paths over it (something like the size of Wyoming).

[image]

Again, this is not an accurate representation of actual air travel - it's more like a worst case scenario of where planes could be.

> Experiment to map many of the airline flights between world airports. It's not showing real time positions (which would be amazing but I don't have that data) but rather, great-circle routes between major airports based on flight data from the [Open Flights](http://openflights.org/data.html) site. As a visualization, I think it fails since there is so much data that around major airports, it just blurs into a mess. Still, it was fun to do and looks kind of pretty (for some definition of pretty).

Comment: Where's Hawaii?

Comment: It’s out there.  You’ll have to go to the website and check it out.   I didn’t want to post 4-6 pictures with all sides of the earth.

Comment: The middle of northern Pacific Ocean seems good. Dry land is merely a preference.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I was thinking of the south Pacific where there actually are some islands to be on.

Answer (score 5):

Anywhere that's not too close to an airport and cloudy with low ceilings would work, as most planes would then be flying above the clouds, where you can't see them, and too high to hear.

Comment: It's certainly possible to hear planes through clouds.  How high does an airplane have to be before it is inaudible?  How sensitive is OP's hearing?

Comment: @phoog I'm not sure, but, for reference, I live about 100 km as the plane flies from the closest airport and I've never heard a plane anywhere near my house, but I can see them. I do live under a flight route. How high are planes after 100 km?

Comment: @phoog I live in an area on the approaches to Amsterdam, aircraft fly over at 7000ft. Most days I can see them but not hear them. In some weather conditions you can hear them, faintly. So add a few thousand feet to that, or even double it for good measure.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest option is just to stay indoors (and not look out of the windows). To do that for a long period of time, I’d suggest a northern city that has a very cold climate in winter, and is set up so that you can get around in the city without going outdoors — Montreal, for example.

Comment: [Krubera cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krubera_Cave) is another option - 7,000 feet underground you will neither see nor hear any aeroplanes!

Answer (score 4):

I lived in rural Nebraska along the Kansas state line and only occasionally saw a commercial jet.    In 5 years I never actually heard one -- just barely saw one way up high.

What I DID see, though, was crop dusters.   I recall waking up at 7 am on a Saturday morning as they were buzzing the house to spray the field just outside of town.

Comment: That's  unusual. Southern Nebraska is quite busy: most of the traffic from Denver going east go (or vice versa) and east coast to/from California goes over there.

Comment: I'm talking far southern, central -- about 10 miles from Kansas.   I imagine there is a corridor a bit farther north that you'll see a lot.    But that's a great illustration -- by traveling not too far, you can be in a pretty quiet area.

Comment: @Hilmar the Nebraska-Kansas border is nearly 600 km long, so I suppose the situation may vary from one place to another.  In my (relatively limited) experience flying between Los Angeles and New York, I've mostly been on the southern route, I guess because of weather, and nowhere near Nebraska.

Comment: At the very moment of this writing, three planes crossed the border: LAX->EWR, LAS->BOS, LAX->MDW. 3 planes for a 600 km border isn't a lot but it looks like there is about one every 10 seconds at the moment, so it adds up quickly. Your mileage will vary obviously but today it looks pretty busy there. .

Comment: What about [B-1s from Ellsworth Air Force Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellsworth_Air_Force_Base)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think you've mistaken the location. Depending on exactly where on the Nebraska-Kansas border Keith was living, he was between 450 and 800km away from Ellsworth, so the chance of traffic would be almost zero. I doubt Ellsworth is the closest USAF base to anywhere on the NE-KS border: for most places, it'll be Offut (near Omaha) and farther west, probably McConnell (near Wichita, KS) (at least among the bases that look like they have a lot of flight operations; there's a missile base in south-east Wyoming and various command centres in Colorado that would be closer).

Comment: I grew up near there, intensely interested in astronomy and thus always staring into the night sky, and the amount of air traffic visible at night makes me quite astonished that you never managed to catch any of it. I'd regularly hear small single-engine planes, too. Incidentally, the first time I ever heard a noise loud enough that I almost panicked was as a teenager, weed-eating a farmer's roadside ditch while wearing over-ear hearing protection and despite that heard a B-1 flying overhead, even before I could see it above the treeline. Forbes Field was hosting an air show that weekend.

Comment: I have no idea what Forbes Field is.   As someone else pointed out, that state line is a long one.  Perhaps we're simply speaking of different areas.

Comment: Right now, on Flightradar24 I'm seeing a long line of flights out of Denver (several of them headed for Washington or Indianapolis) that fly parallel to the _entire length_ of the Nebraska/Kansas state line, about 20 miles north of Kansas. On a clear day their contrails, if they leave any, ought to be perfectly visible from any position "10 miles from Kansas".

Answer (score 4):

Antarctica?

As is frequently shown in debates between flat Earthers and sane people, there is no commercially viable route that actually crosses Antarctica on a great circle.  South America, Australia and Africa are spaced at roughly 120 degree intervals around the South Pole. (There's one route that occasionally clips an  edge of the continent if wind causes deviation from a great circle route -- I have forgotten the details).

Your choice might widen if you are willing to disregard airliners at cruising altitude, which are totally inaudible and all but invisible except when weather conditions favour the creation of contrails.

If you want somewhere more habitable, [Tristan da Cuhna](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tristan+da+Cunha/@-38.726273,-15.6330098,3.27z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x25a3b1a1af6dc9b:0x69ee2d95dc98aedb!8m2!3d-37.1052489!4d-12.2776838) appears to be in  almost the same category as Antarctica. The only possible route I can see that more or less crosses it, is Sao Paolo to Cape Town. I don't know if that route exists.

Comment: Contrails?, Don't you mean chemtrails? :)

Comment: There are regular flights to a number of Antarctic bases. It might be simple to identify parts of Antarctica that will be quiet, but certainly not the entire continent.

Comment: @GlenYates: Oh, you must be from the US. In British English it's "contrail".

Comment: @HenningMakholm cannot tell if serious

Comment: @Almo: https://xkcd.com/1677/

Comment: I hadn't seen that xkcd, my comment was intended as a tip of the tinfoil hat to the flat Earthers mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Related: [What (if any) regularly scheduled airline flights pass over Antarctica?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4310/31076)

Comment: "airliners at cruising altitude, which are totally inaudible and all but invisible except when weather conditions favour the creation of contrails." Go outside on a clear night and look up. It turns out that they are quite visible. You can easily see their strobes from more than a hundred miles away.

Comment: +1: Surely Tristan da Cunha is closest thing to the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

As a general answer - remote locations in narrow deep valleys are potential candidates. Factors that influence suitability include proximity to 'civilisation', major cities, airports of any sort and air routes. I live in New Zealand. Much of the southern part of our country consists of extremely rugged and mountainous terrain and I am certain that numerous areas would meet your requirement - but it would take research to establish which are most liable to.

Once you found a NZ area that met your specification apart from random unfortunate incidents it may even be possible to obtain the cooperation of local aircraft operators to stay out of a very tightly defined area. You'd no doubt need to satisfy those concerned that you did not have ulterior motives.

You specifically mentioned chemtrails. You may have to take special security precautions to hide the plan from the chemtrail establishment and it seems logical that anyone in the chemtrail generation business would want to crash any ;party' that seeks to exclude them. This applies for any site you choose.

---

[**The Chatham Islands**](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Chatham+Islands/@-43.9167848,-176.3916219,52834m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x72b3e865a9c7e733:0x4fc6445640ca2f88!8m2!3d-44.0237474!4d-175.9304546?hl=en) are almost 1000 km to the East of the New Zealand mainland. 
There is an airport used by flights to/from the mainland (located on the tongue of land between the upper and lower lagoons approximately central to the island. There will be locations on the island where the topography and location would make mainland - Chathams flights inevident.

---

The extremely remote and bleak [**"Auckland Islands"**](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Chatham+Islands/@-50.7213038,166.2758568,64964m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x72b3e865a9c7e733:0x4fc6445640ca2f88!8m2!3d-44.0237474!4d-175.9304546?hl=en) are located almost 1000 km to the south of the NZ mainland. There is no airport. Helicopters occasionally visit - almost exclusively on rescue missions when scientific parties 'get into trouble' - as happens occasionally - when the helicopter flights are rare enough to be news worthy. (One was lost near the islands recently and the crew of 3 were extremely lucky (as well as skillful) to survive).

If more ruggedness and isolation is required the further still to the South-East and unplesantly closer to Antarctica [**Campbell Island**](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Chatham+Islands/@-52.5497942,169.2758812,27329m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x72b3e865a9c7e733:0x4fc6445640ca2f88!8m2!3d-44.0237474!4d-175.9304546?hl=en) would almost certainly 'fill the bill".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An option might be **North Korea**. For political reasons international flights go *around* instead of *over*, so there would be much fewer overflights than in most other inhabited places.

Most scheduled international flights from Pyongyang go west across the Yellow Sea, but Wikipedia says there is a route to Vladivostok. ATC maps suggest it flies due east across the country and then up the east coast.

There are also some domestic flights, and I'd imagine information about their exact flight paths is very hard to come by. Finding a place away from the domestic routes will to some extent be a matter of guesswork; the best you can do is probably to pick a place that is not near the straight line between Pyongyang and any of the larger cities. Somewhere like Hwapyong looks like a relatively safe guess.

Getting permission to go there will no doubt be an adventure in itself.

Comment: and then there's the large DPRK air force. Don't know how much they actually fly, but they do have a decent number of aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

There are way too many places that will never see planes overhead; and it is very hard to prove a negative.

Northern Canada, Alaska, Northern Europe, Probably most of eastern Russia, Center of Africa, as well as the center of the Amazon and southern Argentina.

and most probably in the middle of the South Pacific ocean.

Comment: What makes you think those are places that will never see planes overhead? Flights between Western Europe and Japan fly over Northen Europe and Siberia. Flights between central/east North America and China commonly fly over Northern Canada, Alaska, and Siberia. Flights between the Persian Gulf and North Americal often fly over northern Scandinavia and across Canada. Routes to/from Addis Ababa or Lagos _alone_ overfly much of Africa, and that's even before we start counting Europe to South Africa routes.

Comment: As I wrote, it is impossible to prove that a plane will never pass over those areas, but the probability is low in respect to the size of the territories.

Comment: Judging from the number of tracks I can find _right now_ on Flightradar24 that have passed through those areas since they took off, it looks doubtful to me that there's _anywhere_ in those land areas that hasn't had an airliner in cruise pass within 100 km of it during the last 24 hours. Unless you're down in a valley, a contrail at that distance will be easily visible. If it doesn't make a contrail (which depends on meteorological circumstances) actually spotting it will be more hit-and-miss but it's still _in the sky_.

Comment: Settlements in northern Canada are almost *entirely* connected by air. Same with many areas of Alaska.

Comment: and then there's the very regular military patrols over the areas, especially Northern Canada, Alaska and Scandinavia.

Comment: I think this answer suffers from implicitly assuming the earth is flat. Planes generally take the shortest route, which is a Great Circle. US to Europe flies near the North Pole as a result, especially Eastern Europe to Western US. As other comments mention, Antarctica is a much better answer. There's far less population living nearby.

Comment: Northern Canada and Alaska is actually very busy airspace. Nearly all flights from North America to East or Central Asia fly there, as well as some between Western North America and Europe.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.  Of the options presented, I think the Taj Mahal would be a good choice.  Or the Boundary Waters Canoe Wilderness Area might be what you're looking for:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibited_airspace

Comment: The airspace over BWCA is not prohibited all the way up. See comments to Rupert Morrish's answer.

Comment: Likewise, Taj Mahal does seem to have a _small_ exclusion zone, but it's not all that difficult to find flights whose contrails (if they form, and assuming clear skies) would be perfectly visible from Agra.

Answer (score 1):

The [Boundary Waters Canoe Area](https://bwca.com/) wilderness in Minnesota and Ontario is not, as I had thought before researching this answer, off limits to planes. There is a minimum altitude for planes of ~850m (2,800 feet), which would mean that you could possibly see and hear them, but I have never seen or heard a plane or contrail there.

But then, I haven't spent a whole month up there. 14 day limit at one campsite, so you'll be moving, and you have to pack everything in and out.

Comment: One random data point: According to Flightradar24, FI657 (Keflavik - Minneapolis) flew over the area last Thursday, passing 38,000 feet above the east end of Brule Lake at 17:13 local time.

Comment: And **right this moment** AC171 (Toronto-Edmonton) is passing over Isabella Lake at 36,000 feet.

Comment: United 448 (BOS-DEN) is flying over that area right now. UA1502 (Chicago-Fairbanks,) AC8595 (Montreal-Winnipeg,) AC1116 (Regina-Toronto,) and B6633 (BOS-SFO) should also currently be visible from there. Lots of U.S. and Canadian trans-con traffic, trans-Pac traffic to/from the Eastern U.S., and some traffic from the U.S. to Europe also flies through that area.

Answer (score 1):

#### Northwest Scotland (except military jets)

There aren't any major airports in the northwest of Scotland - your closest places that take jets are Glasgow (south), Edinburgh (southeast) or Aberdeen (northeast), and international flights don't tend to go that way.

On the downside, Scotland is (or used to be) a major training area for the military. In the 1980s when I went there as a kid, most days you'd see either F111s or Tornados, depending on who was practising. I don't believe it's as active these days though, because most of the old Cold War squadrons have either been disbanded or have been deployed round the world. So you're reasonably likely to be plane-free.

Comment: All of Scotland lies right under the quite busy routes between continental Europe and North America. As one random example (which happens to be in the air right now so it was easy to find on Flightradar24) [AM 26 from Amsterdam to Mexico City](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/am26#205c142b) flew across Scotland in a line roughly from Dundee to Harris about 4 hours ago. There are plenty of similar overflights, especially in the afternoon, and being about 10 km up they're visible far and wide. It's not comparable to being in Kew, but it's certainly not "never see a plane".

Answer (score 1):

You won't hear or see trails from planes in pretty much 80% of Australia. Of course you won't see much else there either.

You could definitely get out a lens and see some planes maybe 2-5 times a day, but you'd be hard pressed to actually visually identify any planes.

The Australian climate don't allow for planes to have plane trails most of the time.

Comment: Surprisingly (to me and, probably, to you) a look at the Flightstream plot of Australia shows many flights crisscrossing the outback. See https://callumprentice.github.io/apps/flight_stream/index.html# and look at Australia.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: The west coast of Tasmania looks promising, though.

Comment: Yes. Crisscrossing a couple times a day. Not exactly going to be visible since there's no point in flying low at that altitude and there won't be contrails.

Answer (score 1):

From the SkyStream page linked in [JPhi1618's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/137809/31165), there appear to be a couple of dry-land options in the South Atlantic & South Indian Ocean that might work.

- [South Georgia Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Georgia_Island), a UK possession, has [permanent structures](https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2017/12/07/bm_05043692_bs_0000000009608890_slide-666215dbff17114819fb5e4df65bfec306113ea4-s800-c85.jpg) and a small population of scientists from the British Antarctic Survey plus a few government officials.  Its location in the South Atlantic lies on the great-circle route between Tierra del Fuego and Cape Horn, which means that not a lot of commercial flights would be expected to ever overfly it.  Antarctic cruise ships and yachts chartered from the Falkland Islands do regularly visit, so there's actually a reasonable method to get there & back.  Accommodations might be an issue, though.
- The [Prince Edward Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Edward_Islands) are South African possessions in the southwestern Indian Ocean.  They are officially a nature preserve, with a few dozen of scientists living on them at any one time, but no permanent population.   The island had a problem with feral cats hunting the seabirds, so they eradicated the cats, and now the island is overrun with mice — which are also attacking the seabirds.  Maybe you could volunteer to help out with that while you're there.
- Similarly, the [Crozet Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crozet_Islands) are French possessions in the southwestern Indian Ocean.  The situation is similar to the other two:  lots of seabirds and a few scientists.  These islands, however, are starting to get a bit close to the Johannesburg–Sydney great circle route, so there's a greater risk of seeing a plane here than if you visited one of the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the US government if you can come visit Area 51 in Nevada, planes are not allowed close.
And while you are there, take some pictures of the aliens too :-)

Comment: **Civilian** planes are not.  There's an airport there.

Comment: To expand on Loren's comment, the official name of "Area 51" is "Homey Airport".  Not the sort of place you'd go to avoid air traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want on any latitude and longitude - even in on the coordinates of busy places such as New York, L.A., Berlin etc. - as long as you are willing to [climb to a very high altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tourism).

> During the period from 2001 to 2009, 7 space tourists made 8 space flights aboard a Russian Soyuz spacecraft brokered by Space Adventures to the International Space Station (...) On June 7, 2019, NASA announced that starting in 2020, the organization aims to start allowing private astronauts to go on the International Space Station, with the use of SpaceX's Crew Dragon spacecraft and Boeing's Starliner spacecraft for public astronauts, which is planned to be priced at 35,000 USD per day for one astronaut.

Planes only go higher than the International Space Station on rare occasions. For example, the Hubble telescope might need servicing, so a Space Shuttle (a special kind of plane) would be sent with the crew to fix it, and the Hubble does fly 160 km higher (~100 miles) than the ISS - but it very rarely passes over the ISS, and the Space Shuttle is now retired. Seems like there isn't a replacement for it yet and there won't be one for the next year, so it'll be prime time for you to do some astronauting!